# Send BroadcastReceiver data in Activity to a Dialog as it comes in

Tags: java, android, dialog

I have an Activity where I'm receiving some string data through Bluetooth. I need to send this data to a dialog which is already opened as it comes from Bluetooth.

```
//Getting Bluetooth data from the receiver
private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String data = intent.getStringExtra("Status");

            //I need to send data from here to a dialog


        }
    }
};
```

and my Dialog is normal DialogFragment

Data will be coming counties through Broadcast and I need to get it in Dialog.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check top visible fragment if its your dialog fragment then you need to pass your data into your dialog fragment:-

```
// this code inside your onReceive()
String data = intent.getStringExtra("Status");
Fragment fragment = getTopVisibleFragment(getSupportFragmentManager(),R.id.fragment_container);
if (fragment != null && fragment instanceof DialogFragment) {
      fragment.setData(data);
}


public static Fragment getTopVisibleFragment (FragmentManager manager, int containerId) {
    return manager.findFragmentById(containerId);
}
```